# How to get parameters from the URL in Liferay

Tags: java, liferay, liferay-7

I have a portlet developed in Liferay, in which I want to get query parameter value from URL.

I tried this way but get "null" value from Query parameter:

```
HttpServletRequest httpReq = PortalUtil.getHttpServletRequest(request);
HttpServletRequest httpOrigReq = PortalUtil.getOriginalServletRequest(httpReq);
String myValue = httpOrigReq.getParameter("idProcessOrigin");
```

Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code you mention in your question *should* work, however, it's ignoring the peculiarities of a portlet environment. Typically, in a portlet, you'd rather "decorate" the names of parameters with `<portlet:namespace/>` (or whatever the equivalent in your UI library of choice is to this JSP tag). Instead of submitting a parameter `"idProcessOrigin"`, you'd submit `"<portlet:namespace/>idProcessOrigin"` (of course, with properly replaced namespace, e.g. rather `SOME_RANDOM_STUFF_idProcessOrigin`)

If you don't want this, you can also declare the property `com.liferay.portlet.requires-namespaced-parameters=<boolean>` in your portlet-@Component's property list ([as carried over from liferay-portlet.xml](https://dev.liferay.com/develop/reference/-/knowledge_base/7-0/portlet-descriptor-to-osgi-service-property-map))

For the standard way of obtaining the parameters from a portlet request, you don't need to go through the `HttpServletRequest` at all - just use the `PortletRequest`'s `getParameter` method. The result of this method depends, however, on properly decorated parameter names (or the deactivated option mentioned above). Note: When you call `request.getParameter("idProcessOrigin")`, you don't need the decoration any more, provided that `request` is a PortletRequest, not an HttpServletRequest.

Comment: Olaf Thank you for your answer, i want to get the parameter in the controller not in the jsp !

Comment: You'll *get* the parameter in the controller exactly as described here. You'll just have to *name* it according to the rules, and I've documented how to name it in terms of JSP.